# Barchart Bar width is very thin in jasper

Tags: jasper-reports, bar-chart, jfreechart

I have Created one Barchart in ireport 3.0, the problem is that the bars are very thin. When i tried to increase bar width through customize r class it doesn't reflect any changes in size of bar i.e. width is same as it was. So how to increase width of bars of bar chart? I am attaching an image copy for your understanding purpose.

[image]
Bar width is shown in figure.

[image: Bar width]

Comment: There is no figure. And please check formatting of your question. (click "edit" button below the question, left side)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to properly indent your text. Indentation by 4 spaces is for code samples - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue as well. After a long search i found some solutions which fixed my issue. jasper report bar chart's bar width depends on chart's height and width. as jasper use JFreechart in backend so many modifications possible by a customize class. For increasing bar's width you need a customization class and then add it to your barchart jrxml like bellow

```
public class JasperBarChartCustomization implements JRChartCustomizer {
@Override
public void customize(JFreeChart chart, JRChart jasperChart) {
    CategoryPlot catPlot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
    BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) catPlot.getRenderer();
    renderer.setMaximumBarWidth(.08);//for max width//
    renderer.setItemMargin(-2);//as much margin decrease that much bar width increase//
    //for adding value ob bar//
    renderer.setBasePositiveItemLabelPosition(new ItemLabelPosition(ItemLabelAnchor.CENTER, TextAnchor.CENTER));
    renderer.setBaseItemLabelPaint(Color.WHITE);
    renderer.setBaseItemLabelFont(new Font("fontname", Font.PLAIN, 6));
    //for remove legend background color and box border//
    if (chart.getLegend() != null) {
        chart.getLegend().setBorder(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        LegendTitle legend = chart.getLegend();
        legend.setBorder(0, 0, 0, 0);
        legend.setFrame(BlockBorder.NONE);
    }
  }
}
```

Now create a jar from above class and use that jar in ur jasper project's classpath

If your jasper run inside java application then u can use the class directly without making jar. create customize class in you code base